# preserving column names with softImpute::softImpute command in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm trying to impute missing variables in a large data frame (around 4000 variables). I used the softImp command, but it does not preserve the column names, but renames them as X1...X4000 after running the code.

fin.train is my dataframe.

```
install.packages("softImute"); library(softImpute)
# Construct a training set
softImp = softImpute(as.matrix(fin.train), rank.max = 60)
data.comp = softImp$u %*% diag(softImp$d) %*% t(softImp$v)
data.comp=data.frame(data.comp)
fin.train[fin.train==NA]=data.comp[fin.train==NA]
```

would there be a way I can preserve column names? I'm trying to perform regression after this, so I would need to keep the variable names intact.

Comment: First off, have you checked what `fin.train==NA` gives you. It's not what you think you should get. Try `is.na(fin.train)`

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing is.na instead but it doesn't seem to preserve the non-missing values in fin.train.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it yet (in the absence of any data) but what about:

```
 fin.train[ !complete.cases(fin.train), ] = data.comp[ !complete.cases(fin.train), ]
```

If the names are still missing, then perhaps:

```
colnames(fin.train) <- colnames(data.comp)
```

I find myself wondering if this will work (logical indexing):

```
fin.train[ is.na(fin.train) ] <- data.comp{ is.na(fin.train) ]
```

Or possibly converting to numerical indexing:

```
 fin.train[ which( is.na(fin.train), arr.ind=TRUE)  ] <- 
                                 data.comp[ which( is.na(fin.train), arr.ind=TRUE) ]
```

Comment: Thank you! The code colnames worked! However the first code yielded error Error in `[.data.frame`(data.comp, !complete.cases(fin.train)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Well, are their number of rows and columns the same? And are there any missing values in data.comp? There's quite a bit of missing code  in your question as well as a complete and total lack of description of the data.

Comment: I'm sorry my question lacked elaboration. So fin.train has missing values and I'm trying to impute missing values and create data.comp. My problem is that after doing the code above (softImpute) the non-missing values are replaced as well. I've managed to preserve the column names after doing colnames so the rows and the columns are the same.

Comment: Looking again I see that I used the indexing incorrectly (one of the consequences of having no test set to work on.) I'm really flying blind here because of all the missing information, so the update remains a wild-assed guess.

Comment: I'm sorry again for lack of information. The fin.data has near 4000 variables and 4000 observations. There are missing values for some of the numeric variables, and I'm trying to do imputation.

Comment: Yes, ... and the `data.comp` object?